# ¿Do you know if it is possible to obtain the real IMEI of the device?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

I have tried several codes but I cannot do it, I'm a kotlin learner. please help me.

i has problem using this line:

the error say:

Permission is only granted to system apps.

My Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.q11">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: If your app isn’t privileged, you can’t use the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission. So, no this isn’t possible unless you are writing privileged or system apps.